# D3.js + React - Displaying multiple tooltips in line chart

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, graph, charts

I have built a line chart with D3 in React, and I'm trying to add multiple lines displaying a tooltip on each line while hovering over them. I'm stuck with the tooltip part. Right now, only one of the tooltips is showing, and it seems to be the last rendered line that gets it.

This is what my component looks like:

```
class LineChart extends Component {

      wrapper = React.createRef();

      componentDidMount() {
        const { dataSets } = this.props

        let svg = d3.select("body svg.mySvg"),
          margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
          width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
          height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom;

        const bisectDate = d3.bisector(function(d) { return d.year; }).left;

        const x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]);
        const y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

        const line = d3.line()
          .x(function(d) { return x(d.year); })
          .y(function(d) { return y(d.value); });

        let g = svg.append("g")
          .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

        x.domain(d3.extent(dataSets.jitter, function(d) { return d.year; }));
        y.domain([0, d3.max(dataSets.jitter, function(d) { return d.value; })]);

        g.append("g")
          .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
          .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
          .style("color", "#fff")
          .call(d3.axisBottom(x).ticks(3))
          .selectAll("text")
            .style("text-anchor", "end")
            .attr("dx", "-.8em")
            .attr("dy", ".3em")
            .attr("transform", "rotate(-45)");

        g.append("g")
          .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
          .style("color", "#fff")
          .call(d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(7).tickFormat(function(d) { return d; }));

        [dataSets.jitter, dataSets.latency].forEach((data, index) => {

          g.append("path")
            .datum(data)
            .attr("class", "line")
            .attr("d", line);

          let focus = g.append("g")
            .attr("class", `focus focus-${index}`)
            .style("display", "none");

          focus.append("line")
            .attr("class", "y-hover-line hover-line")
            .attr("x1", width)
            .attr("x2", width);

          focus.append("circle")
            .attr("r", 7.5);

          focus.append("text")
            .attr("class", `text text-${index}`)
            .style("color", "#fff")
            .attr("x", 15)
            .attr("dy", ".31em");

          svg.append('rect')
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
            .attr("class", `overlay overlay-${index}`)
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height)
            .on("mouseover", function() { focus.style("display", null); })
            .on("mouseout", function() { focus.style("display", "none"); })
            .on("mousemove", function() {
              var x0 = x.invert(d3.mouse(this)[0]),
                  i = bisectDate(data, x0, 1),
                  d0 = data[i - 1],
                  d1 = data[i],
                  d = x0 - d0.year > d1.year - x0 ? d1 : d0;
              focus.attr("transform", "translate(" + x(d.year) + "," + y(d.value) + ")");
              focus.select(`text.text-${index}`)
                .style("color", "#fff")
                .style("stroke", "#fff")
                .text(function() { return d.value; });
            });
        }) 
      }

      render() {
        const { width, height } = this.props
        return  (
            <svg
              ref={ this.wrapper }
              height={ height }
              width={ width }
              className="mySvg"
            ></svg>
        )
      }
    }
```

The prop dataSets looks like this:

```
{
  latency: [
    { year: 2011, value: 3 },
    { year: 2012, value: 20 },
    { year: 2013, value: 2 },
    { year: 2014, value: 12 },
    { year: 2015, value: 8 },
    { year: 2016, value: 14 },
    { year: 2017, value: 8 }
  ],
  jitter: [
    { year: 2011, value: 1 },
    { year: 2012, value: 28 },
    { year: 2013, value: 5 },
    { year: 2014, value: 12 },
    { year: 2015, value: 6 },
    { year: 2016, value: 4 },
    { year: 2017, value: 7 }
  ]
}
```

So my idea was to render each line and tooltip in every iteration of `[dataSets.jitter, dataSets.latency].forEach`, ([line 44 here](https://pastebin.com/dDbVRdeX)) which seems to work for just rendering the lines, but not both of the tooltips, only the last. If I change the order in the array so that dataSets.latency if before dataSets.jitter, the tooltip will show for that line instead.

Does it have to do with the mouseover event only being registered to the last one, and if so, how come?

Comment: your overlay rects mask each other only the top one gets the mouse events

Comment: Ah right, thank you!